# Calculate intersection point between line and polygon with Boost.Geometry

Tags: c++, boost, geometry, boost-geometry

I want the calculation of an intersection point of a line and a polygon, or two lines, etc. How to calculate this point using Boost.Geometry?

Answer (score 1):

In case someone stumbles upon this like I did, as hinted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29921371), the operation performed by `bg::intersection` actually depends on the type of object you provide as a result.

Let's define

```
typedef bg::model::d2::point_xy<double> BPoint;
typedef bg::model::multi_point<BPoint> BMultiPoint;
typedef bg::model::multi_linestring<BLineString> BMultiLineString;
```

then, running

```
BMultiPoint mp;
bg::intersection(line, polygon, mp);
bg::intersection(line, other_line, mp);
```

will return the intersection points between the `polygon` and the `line`, then between the `line` and the `other_line`.

On the other hand, note that

```
BMultiLineString mls;
bg::intersection(line, polygon, mls);
```

Will return the subparts of `line` where it overlaps with `polygon`.

Answer (score 0):

although i never used boost library in my uni years we had to make this kind of calculations in a very basic 2d game engine.

I have solved it back then with vectors, i had a vector for position and one for direction of a line, and calculated the colision point with another line based on given information. (using atan2 to know the direction in radians/degrees)

when i did that with an object (a square) i have taken the 4 corners of the object and calculated if the position of the line at given Y positions (being Y values the top and bottom of the square) was within the X area of the square.

i am currently at work so i cant give you the code i used, but this should give you a rough idea of the approach.

i know this is not exactly what you are looking for, but it may be helpful for future reference

Comment: hello thank you for the answer, the calculation of the problem is very simple and i have a working program. But i want use Boost.Geometry for solving because this is better tested and faster.